# Not able to execute any test case in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, fixtures, psychopy, psych

I am really confused about this Psych BadAlias error.
I have tried everything but not able to debug this error.

When i am executing my test case i am getting this error

```
 Failure/Error: @st.fetch(o.anchor) { raise BadAlias, "Unknown alias: #{o.anchor}" }
     
     Psych::BadAlias:
       Unknown alias: 2
```

But before it was working perfectly fine.

This is my fixtures file
workers.yml

```
Worker_1:
  name: Hello
  preferred_first_name: First
  preferred_last_name: Last
  assignment: Assignemnt_1
  talent: Ruby_development
```

Any kind of Help is appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Please share the full stacktace of the error.

Comment: Have you tried removing parts of the yml file to see if one attribute/value is causing this specifically? to narrow down what's the exact place this is failing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, as there was just a syntax error in yaaml file.
we canot use "p-r-a-t-i-k" we have to use "p_r_a_t_i_k"

Answer (score 0):

A **Psych::BadAlias** exception will be raised if the `yaml` contains aliases but the `aliases` keyword argument is set to `false`.
Please check your `yaml` files. The error got raised from [here](https://github.com/ruby/psych/blob/25e6c6be06c14f9ec89230d4be5117332bf88249/lib/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb#L325). For more details please refer [here](https://github.com/ruby/psych/blob/25e6c6be06c14f9ec89230d4be5117332bf88249/lib/psych.rb#L311)